# VBA Collection issue

Tags: excel, vba

I an trying towrite a simple VBA code where some cell values are combined.
Problem with code bellow is that `Cell` Object in the loop keeps selecting whole row, not just one cell in `Row` Collection

```
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Row As Range

Set Row = Rows(ActiveCell.Row)
Set Cell = ActiveCell

For Each Cell In Row
    With Cell
        If IsNumeric(InStr(1, Right(.Value, 1), "/")) Then
            .Value = .Value & .Offset(0, 1).Value
             .Offset(0, 1).Delete (xlShiftToLeft)
        End If
    End With
Next Cell
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? I think that would make it easier for us to work out a solution.

Comment: Sure For each cell that ends with "/" I want t append to it value from cell to the right, and delete cell to the right( as an clear content of the cell to the right, and shift all cells afterwards to the left).

Comment: Also, to confirm, are you looking across an entire row? For example, check Cell A1 first, then Cell B1, then Cell C1? In this case, what should happen when the cell to the right has already been deleted?

Comment: Yes this is correct. and if the cell already has been deleted skip it meaning  if C1 was deleted( and D1, E1 .......   shifted the the left), then continue from C1( which now should have contents previously belonging to D1 due to the shift)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. For this example, assumptions made about data being on Sheet1 and the start row (stRow) and start col (testCol) of the data.  Amend these to suit your conditions.

```
Option Explicit
Sub combine()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, testCol As Long, endCol As Long
Dim rnum As Long, cnum As Long
Dim cl As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
stRow = 1
testCol = 1

    With ws
        endRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, testCol).End(xlUp).Row

            For rnum = stRow To endRow
                endCol = .Cells(rnum, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    For cnum = testCol To endCol - 1
                        Set cl = .Cells(rnum, cnum)
                            If Right(cl, 1) = "/" And Right(cl.Offset(0, 1), 1) <> "/" Then
                                If IsNumeric(Left(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - 1)) Then
                                    cl.Value = cl.Value & cl.Offset(0, 1).Value
                                    cl.Offset(0, 1).Delete (xlShiftToLeft)
                                End If
                            End If
                    Next cnum
            Next rnum
    End With
End Sub
```

Although not specified by you, this code does not combine an adjacent cell which also has a trailing "/". This on the basis that we shouldn't 'remove' a 'test' value. If this condition not required it is easily changed.